# BigQuery: Hashing a String Doesn't Match CityHash

Tags: hash, google-bigquery

Trying to get my external CityHash to return the same value as BigQuery Hash(). 
Here are the values I'm trying to match:
[image: BigQuery Hash Examples]

The only hashed string that matches is a blank string.

In the [BigQuery Query Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference), it mentions that it uses the CityHash libarary. I've tried using multiple external libraries for CityHash, and they're all consistent with each other, but not with BigQuery Hash()

Here is an example of CityHash in Go (Golang):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "bitbucket.org/creachadair/cityhash"
)

func main() {
    var bytesToHash = []byte("mystringtohash")

    myHash := int64(cityhash.Hash64(bytesToHash))
    fmt.Printf("Hashed version of '%s': %d\n", bytesToHash, myHash)

    bytesToHash = []byte("")
    myHash = int64(cityhash.Hash64(bytesToHash))
    fmt.Printf("Hashed version of '%s': %d\n", bytesToHash, myHash)
}
```

Here is the output from my program:

```
Hashed version of 'mystringtohash': -6615946700494525143
Hashed version of '1234': 882600748797058222
Hashed version of '': -7286425919675154353
```

Is BigQuery doing something special with the string before hashing it?

Comment: Can you please update your post showing the output of your program.

Comment: For me BigQuery results are consistent with C++ cityhash library, and I cannot run your Go program in Go playground, it doesn't find import cityhash (and I know nothing about Go programs)

Comment: Ok, I added the result from the Go code. Thanks for having a look...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I spent some time going through the code, and here is what I think happened.

- BigQuery's implementation of CityHash is based on code in version 1.0.3 (can be still downloaded from here https://code.google.com/p/cityhash/downloads/detail?name=cityhash-1.0.3.tar.gz)
- The golang implementation you used seems to be a port of version 1.1.1 (can be downloaded from here https://code.google.com/p/cityhash/downloads/detail?name=cityhash-1.1.1.tar.gz)

Unfortunately, these versions seem to be incompatible since version 1.1, as noted in README (emphasis is mine):

> CityHash v1.1, October 22, 2012
>
> - Add CityHash32(), intended for 32-bit platforms.
> - **Change existing functions** to improve their hash quality and/or speed.  > Most
>     of the changes were minor, but CityHashCrc* was substantially reworked
>     (and made perhaps 10% slower, unfortunately).
> - Improve README.

I am not sure what is the right thing to do here, maybe BigQuery should update its implementation to match version 1.1.1, or maybe it will be a breaking change to existing users who rely on it. But at least we know what is going on now.

Comment: Thanks for putting the time in for this answer! I think what we're going to end up using FarmHash instead. Hopefully Google will add that to BigQuery functions one day...

Comment: Note that FarmHash is documented to not be stable across platforms. If a non-stable hash is acceptable to your use case, then an older version of CityHash may work for you as well.

Comment: @Michael Sheldon: That's a great point Definitely something to consider when switching...